# Canvas Pop Up Window by clicking on certain area

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How to make a pop up window by clicking a specific sector of a pie chart in the context of canvas?

Comment: How about you post the code that you tried and didnt work as expected ?

Comment: canvas.onmousedown = function(e){ if(/* do something with e.clientX and e.clientY*/){window.open(“your window”)}}

Comment: You should check out the basic JavaScript & DOM tutorial

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: Hello guys who commented this. I am senior React developer with over 3 y.o. of experience, but exploring possibilities of html canvas - one client requirement is creating dialog after clicking on the node. 
Your answers didn't help at all, please try to be more useful next time. I find nothing wrong about OPs answer.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

try this, this is a popup and the instruction are in this link.
and insted of button you can insert the pie char (img)